# MATLAB. Can't detect line break with FSCANF. Empty char. Why?

Tags: matlab, text-files, scanf, whitespace, line-breaks

I am trying to read lines in a text file character by character, because I am trying to read and modify data files whos last column is comments of varying length with white spaces. But I cannot find any line break character, `fscanf` returns an 1x1 empty(How??) char instead of e.g. `\r\n`. Why is this?

When `fscanf` reads the line break into a variable `tmpChar`, this is the result:

```
>> tmpChar                                 >> size(tmpChar)

tmpChar =                                  ans =

                                                1     1

>>                                         >>
```

---

This is my test code:

```
fileID = fopen('testfile.txt','r+');
iRow = 1;
tmpChar = fscanf(fileID,'%c',1);
while ~isempty(tmpChar)
    fprintf(['Row ', num2str(iRow), ':', blanks(3)]);
    while ~strcmp(tmpChar,'\r\n') && ~isempty(tmpChar)
        fprintf(num2str(tmpChar));
        tmpChar = fscanf(fileID,'%c',1);
    end
    iRow = iRow + 1;
    tmpChar = fscanf(fileID,'%c',1);
end
fprintf('\n');
fclose(fileID);
```

The result from above is:

```
>>TestScript
Row 1:   First line

Second line

Last line
>>
```

but I was expecting

```
>>TestScript
Row 1:   First line
Row 2:   Second line
Row 3:   Last line
>>
```

The problem is that the character array does not contain any character.

---

A line from the text file I am actually working with could look like this:

`newName.mat | oldName.mat | yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss | randomComment includingWhiteSpaces`

I want to be able to read this, save the strings in a cell array, where the comment in the last column is intact.

---

I cannot seem to find a good way of doing this without removing all spaces from the first four columns in the data file, using another character as delimiter. Since I want to ensure readability, that is not a good option. (`newName|oldname|date time|random comment`, with long names => Ugly!)

If I use `textscan` or any other built-in function with a different character than space as delimiter, I could just remove the unwanted spaces in the cell array elements afterwards. However, I'd rather find a more attractive and general method of doing this.

---

I have already posted a question on the same problem, but focused on using `textscan` [[here]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003915/how-do-i-read-the-rest-of-a-line-of-a-text-file-in-matlab-with-textscan). I am now trying to read the line character by character and look for the line break. This method, even though it gives me good control, is still not as general as I would like. However, I am intrigued by the "missing" line break character. Why can I not find it with fscanf, even though other post claim you can?

Please also share any tips of other methods that would work. Thank you!

Comment: `fscanf` used like this reads in a single line (until the next lien break), so it's never going to be equal to a new line character...

Comment: @Wolfie Did you read my answer below? Embarrassingly enough, I found the problem myself 30 minutes after I posted this (to my defense, I did spend a lot of time with it before posting the question). I might be wrong since I am not an expert, but it looks like `fscanf` actually do read line break characters. I stepped through my code and it did read two line breaks at the end of every line, first `\r` then `\n`. I tested like this: `tmpChar == sprintf('\r\n')`. The first "line break reading" gave a logical array `[1 0]`. The second gave similarly `[0 1]`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was not thinking straight. The line break was indeed `\r\n`, however since I was reading one character at a time it got split. Also, I was comparing to the string `\r\n`, not the character itself (which can be created in MATLAB with `sprintf`). So when I reached the end of the line I was reading `\r` first and then kept going in the loop, even when I was using `strcmp` with `sprintf('\r\n')`. The fact that the output had line breaks in it got me thinking of this.

Instead, I did a regular character array comparison and used `sprintf`. That worked. My final code that give the expected output looks like this:

```
fileID = fopen('testfile.txt','r+');
iRow = 1;
tmpChar = fscanf(fileID,'%c',1);
while ~isempty(tmpChar)
    if ~any(tmpChar == sprintf('\r\n')) % Because line break will occur twice in a row.
        iRow = iRow + 1;
        fprintf('\n');            
        fprintf(['Row ', num2str(iRow), ':', blanks(3)]);
    end
    while  ~any(tmpChar == sprintf('\r\n'))
        fprintf(num2str(tmpChar));
        tmpChar = fscanf(fileID,'%c',1);
        if isempty(tmpChar)
            break
        end
    end
    tmpChar = fscanf(fileID,'%c',1);
end
fprintf('\n');
fclose(fileID);
```

I feel stupid, realizing this just after posting this question. But hopefully this might help someone in the future who is also not that experienced in reading data files with MATLAB. However, the last part of this question is still interesting.